# tense of "would be" (when used as a synonym for "was")

Tags: grammar, past-tense

In a school paper, my son wrote the sentence, "In 1763, the stalemate would be broken." His teacher told him to avoid the "past progressive tense." The phrase "would be" is clearly *not* an example of the past progressive tense--but I can't quite figure out what tense it is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, *would* is a modal verb that doesn't have a tense per se.

From the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/modality-tense):

> Modal verbs do not change in form to make different tenses.
>
> All of the modal verbs can refer to present and future time. Only some of them can refer to past time.

In the case of your sentence, *would* is referring to a past event.

Comment: This tense is often called 'future in the past'.  It isn't necessary here because a time reference is given, so it can simply be 'past'.

Answer (score -1):

First, the sentence of your son is

> In 1763, the stalemate **would be broken**.

so the verb is **would be broken**, and not just **would be**. It's a passive construction. The active counterpart would be:

> In 1763, [something] **would break** the stalemate.

The use of **would** indicates a *conditional mood*. In this specific example, the tense is *simple conditional* (I would do smth).

N.B: Of course, here *conditional* doesn't imply there is a condition. It refers to a "future in the past" (i.e. future happenings with the past as a time reference).